# Missing dependencies causing Keyring error when opening Spyder3 on Ubuntu18?

Tags: ide, python-3.6, spyder, ubuntu-18.04, python-keyring

I'm fairly new to programming and such. I'm trying to use Spyder3, and I keep getting this error (below). I am using Geforce 1080ti, Ubuntu 18.04.01, python3.3.6, python2 is not installed. I tried $ pip3 install keyring, which is now installed but still receiving error.

```
$ spyder3
Error initializing plugin EntryPoint('Windows (alt)', 'keyrings.alt.Windows', None, Distribution('keyrings.alt', '3.0')).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 163, in _load_plugins
    init_func = ep.load()
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/entrypoints.py", line 77, in load
    mod = import_module(self.module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/Windows.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import file_base
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/file_base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from keyring.util.escape import escape as escape_for_ini
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring.util.escape'
Error initializing plugin EntryPoint('file', 'keyrings.alt.file', None, Distribution('keyrings.alt', '3.0')).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 163, in _load_plugins
    init_func = ep.load()
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/entrypoints.py", line 77, in load
    mod = import_module(self.module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/file.py", line 11, in <module>
    from keyring.util.escape import escape as escape_for_ini
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring.util.escape'
Error initializing plugin EntryPoint('pyfs', 'keyrings.alt.pyfs', None, Distribution('keyrings.alt', '3.0')).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 163, in _load_plugins
    init_func = ep.load()
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/entrypoints.py", line 77, in load
    mod = import_module(self.module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/pyfs.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keyring.util.escape import escape as escape_for_ini
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring.util.escape'
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainter here*) You said: "I'm fairly new to programming and such". Then, please do yourself a favor and download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux), which comes with the latest Spyder (unlike the latest Ubuntu, which comes with a version 10 months old now), it's is very easy to install and has all these problems sorted out for you. By the way, we warn about this [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) and [here](https://www.spyder-ide.org/).

Comment: It's all very well to recommend Anaconda, but it comes with a lot of baggage in terms of additional stuff to learn and heavily customizing your systems's default Python environment.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Fix it with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade keyrings.alt
```

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: I had an exact same error when I tried to use `pip3` after I upgraded its version. This solution fixed it for me too.

Comment: ... and *why* is this necessary? Did you find more information?

Comment: I needed to do it for `pip` instead of `pip3`. Don't really understand why though.

Comment: Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/git-ubuntu/+bug/1794041