# Missing dependency "keyring: None (NoK)" in Spyder 4

Tags: anaconda, spyder, python-keyring

Having recently upgraded to Spyder 4 on Anaconda, I am getting this Error message:

[image]

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53164278/8854526), but that relates to Spyder 3, and is not working in my case.

My system runs on Linux Mint 19 with Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7, Spyder 4.0.0 and Python 2.7.16 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is an error in the way we're registering `keyring` as a dependency because we don't really require it on Linux and Python 2.

It'll be fixed in our next version (**4.0.1**) to be release shortly.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. So, this is not expected to lead to any bug, I hope !

Comment: No, ir doesn't.